# finfo_file(): Failed identify data 0:(null) when creating Ad Image Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using this code to creating an Ad Image to retrieve the image hash for the Ad Creative

```
$image = new AdImage(null, $this->accountId);
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME}'http://koferafb.dev/image/dummy.jpeg';

    $image->create();

    echo $image->{AdImageFields::HASH}.PHP_EOL;
```

The problem is i encounter this error finfo_file(): Failed identify data 0:(null)

Do i need some extension to make this Run? or am i doing this correctly?

Comment: For starters, that isn't valid PHP code.

Comment: do you mean this line?
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = 'http://koferafb.dev/image/dummy.jpeg';